# Cannot resolve domain or ns after changing ns records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I know similar question have been asked, but none of them actually provide any relevant information to my situation

I have two servers with codenames DF and WP, each hosting a number of websites. DF is configured with a cluster ns1 - ns4.dekyfinweb.com while WP is configured with alpha,gamma and delta.dekyfinweb.com. The websites on each server uses the nameservers configured on that server.

Everything was working well till we began to migrate the main website for dekyfinweb.com from DF to WP. We changed the nameservers of the domain from (ns1-ns4) to (alpha, gamma and delta); and the domain with its nameservers stopped resolving after a few hours.

I've used various online dns testing tools, but i can't seem to get any relevant info on the cause of the problem

Below are the results of a few test i run using dig

```
$ dig dekyfinweb.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P1 <<>> dekyfinweb.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 21431
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dekyfinweb.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 423 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 15 14:39:56 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Result of lookup against parent nameserver for .com

```
$ dig @g.gtld-servers.net dekyfinweb.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @g.gtld-servers.net dekyfinweb.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6425
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dekyfinweb.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  alpha.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  gamma.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  delta.dekyfinweb.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
alpha.dekyfinweb.com.   172800  IN  A   137.74.192.129
gamma.dekyfinweb.com.   172800  IN  A   137.74.192.129
delta.dekyfinweb.com.   172800  IN  A   137.74.192.129

;; Query time: 226 msec
;; SERVER: 192.42.93.30#53(192.42.93.30)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 15 16:43:47 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 151
```

gamma and delta actually point to different servers, but I changed the glue records to 137.74.192.129 because they can't sync with alpha

below is a lookup of the nameserver against the IP supplied in the previeous query

```
$ dig @137.74.192.129 alpha.dekyfinweb.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @137.74.192.129 alpha.dekyfinweb.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8980
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;alpha.dekyfinweb.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
alpha.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN  A   137.74.192.129

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  delta.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  gamma.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  alpha.dekyfinweb.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
delta.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN  A   149.56.14.198
gamma.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN  A   149.56.46.18

;; Query time: 129 msec
;; SERVER: 137.74.192.129#53(137.74.192.129)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 15 16:48:15 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 151
```

And finally a lookup of the domain against the IP seems to be working just fine

```
$ dig @137.74.192.129 dekyfinweb.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P1 <<>> @137.74.192.129 dekyfinweb.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9918
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dekyfinweb.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dekyfinweb.com.         14400   IN      A       137.74.192.129

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dekyfinweb.com.         14400   IN      NS      delta.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.         14400   IN      NS      gamma.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.         14400   IN      NS      alpha.dekyfinweb.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
alpha.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN      A       137.74.192.129
delta.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN      A       149.56.14.198
gamma.dekyfinweb.com.   14400   IN      A       149.56.46.18

;; Query time: 793 msec
;; SERVER: 137.74.192.129#53(137.74.192.129)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 15 14:53:58 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 167
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with TTLs.

You have DNSSEC problems, see http://dnsviz.net/d/dekyfinweb.com/WUhiXg/dnssec/

In short, the com zone has a DS record for your domain but you do not publish any DNSKEY record. Hence any validating recursive nameserver (such as Google ones) will detect this case as a terminal error hence the SERVFAIL because it may be either a misconfiguration or an active attack, and both case are not discernable externally. You need to quickly arrange this situation: if you do not understand anything regarding DNSSEC, stop trying to use it, go to your registrar and ask them to remove the DS record from the .COM zone ; if you do really wish to enable DNSSEC on your domain (a worthwhile and noble goal, but not without pitfalls), you need to fix your current configuration.

As long as you stay in the current configuration, your domain name will be broken for any kind of validating recursive nameserver, the situation will never fix itself.

Compare
`dig @8.8.8.8 dekyfinweb.com SOA`
with
`dig @8.8.8.8 dekyfinweb.com SOA +cd`
(the lastest case specifically requests not to do DNSSEC validation, and hence things will work, comparison between these 2 cases show that the problem is related to DNSSEC, as well as the dnsviz output above)

Comment: That's true.  I'm just not sure whether the problem was because I changed the domain registrar or the nameservers. But I'll get to the bottom of it and disable the DNSSEC. Thanks Patrick for the insight

Comment: If you control the nameservers, you are in charge of DNSSEC and the problem may have happened when you changed them and/or changed their setup. If you let your registrar handle DNS resolution for you, the old registrar may have been DNSSEC-aware/active but not the new one, hence after the transfer things started to fail. Transfer of DNSSEC enabled domain names between registrars is currently still an open problem. There are solutions or mitigations but nothing perfect. It involves a lot of care in all cases :-( Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wait about 4 hours. (Your top level seems to have a 4 hour ttl). Looks like Google has just cached a bad entry. Since `dig +trace dekyfinweb.com` appears to work, I expect things to clear up when the ttl expires off.

Comment: This is actually the third day and I was getting troubled. I did a dns propagation test and realized that the problem was from google's dns. As I said, I made the changes 3 days ago so I was expecting everything to work fine

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but cannot comment yet)

I am getting a different result:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> +trace dekyfinweb.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           498957  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           498957  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 415 bytes from 10.137.1.1#53(10.137.1.1) in 55 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            86400   IN  DS  30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20170628220000 20170615210000 14796 . DGPIZzKyA+uBJAdMEKypVNz14HB/y5KZgCco2TP7BQUlkPv8CLNClNqj 2rEpN4ijCk1zk+oQfmQA5Ee35wbrrcwnGqfrRVRffJqRfu8aSRM5eiEA xEpQus8TaanF0FIkkx2CHQOil15nFRZTMtusOPTyxiwYaD5zxJZS0W1N dwbWVzxIwbL9jaImxVLc113cTl/nnnyKUaziCX6jk1/bOh1CrCjctxkp 2qNJ68b7QCIe11g9lmiBQMP2QGQK3aAP21I+bfNvHeGZ6nUADN+P/TsQ lWsM+YEni9W1LcAtc0DTqhHuzxSd6Y3WmMNPZc6FFnJnHR6CcWY+eh6x 3EUCZQ==
;; Received 866 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 201 ms

dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  alpha.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  gamma.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     172800  IN  NS  delta.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     86400   IN  DS  17815 8 2 FE6DDCE11D61B71AECABD8FFD57A58C3A86ACF17F699F210983A1809 13B17AD9
dekyfinweb.com.     86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20170622111241 20170615100241 27302 com. RQaEDdTFmYhnLTOpGPsaI+64VkFmoReqD+2uyDrMhWs0jpBUkcSIz10F gdEtep+hG4G1k1FHb9hvaWNrxfwzYiXXmbRaD5HiDdCPP8A8Qznuo0uY LV7A1cl2wq+Ivi20u216eoAieXjf5RJjyK7mdXuB6ssLJ8Z+6L5+ASDk 454=
;; Received 362 bytes from 192.33.14.30#53(b.gtld-servers.net) in 323 ms

dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  A   188.165.61.100
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  alpha.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  delta.dekyfinweb.com.
dekyfinweb.com.     14400   IN  NS  gamma.dekyfinweb.com.
;; Received 167 bytes from 149.56.14.198#53(delta.dekyfinweb.com) in 206 ms
```

and at that IP, port 80 only, an "Under maintenance" page.

Comment: Thanks Pablo for the effort. I realised that everything is working as expected. The issue was because Google's DNS server was not resolving the domain. Everything works if I use a different DNS server. I can't seem to understand why google's DNS cannot resolve 4 days after I made the changes

Comment: My ISP(which is actually the biggest here) actually uses Google's DNS so the website can't be accessed by the target audience